# Multiply columns in a data frame by a vector

Tags: r

What I want to do is multiply all the values in column 1 of a data.frame by the first element in a vector, then multiply all the values in column 2 by the 2nd element in the vector, etc...

```
c1 <- c(1,2,3)
c2 <- c(4,5,6)
c3 <- c(7,8,9)
d1 <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)

  c1 c2 c3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9

v1 <- c(1,2,3)
```

So the result is this:

```
  c1  c2  c3
1  1  8   21
2  2  10  24
3  3  12  27
```

I can do this one column at a time but what if I have 100 columns? I want to be able to do this programmatically.

Comment: Is the entire dataframe numeric?

Comment: Not the entire data frame for the problem I'm working on. There is a factor column.

Comment: You should include that in your example so that people can take it into account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transposing the dataframe works.

```
c1 <- c(1,2,3)
c2 <- c(4,5,6)
c3 <- c(7,8,9)
d1 <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
t(t(d1)*v1)
#     c1 c2 c3
#[1,]  1  8 21
#[2,]  2 10 24
#[3,]  3 12 27
```

EDIT: If all columns are not numeric, you can do the following

```
c1 <- c(1,2,3)
c2 <- c(4,5,6)
c3 <- c(7,8,9)
d1 <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3)

# Adding a column of characters for demonstration
d1$c4 <- c("rr", "t", "s")

v1 <- c(1,2,3)

#Choosing only numeric columns
index <- which(sapply(d1, is.numeric) == TRUE)
d1_mat <- as.matrix(d1[,index])

d1[,index] <- t(t(d1_mat)*v1)
d1
#  c1 c2 c3 c4
#1  1  8 21 rr
#2  2 10 24  t
#3  3 12 27  s
```

Comment: You'll need to take the factor variable into account.

Comment: That works on my 10 column, 1068 row data frame. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Or simply diagonalize the vector, so that each row entry is multiplied by the corresponding element in v1:

```
c1 <- c(1,2,3)
c2 <- c(4,5,6)
c3 <- c(7,8,9)
d1 <- as.matrix(cbind(c1,c2,c3))
v1 <- c(1,2,3)

d1%*%diag(v1)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    8   21
[2,]    2   10   24
[3,]    3   12   27
```

Comment: This should be the answer - very simple, one step, with no complicated transformations etc.

Answer (score 9):

We can also replicate the vector to make the lengths equal and then multiply

```
d1*v1[col(d1)]
#  c1 c2 c3
#1  1  8 21
#2  2 10 24
#3  3 12 27
```

---

Or use `sweep`

```
sweep(d1, 2, v1, FUN="*")
```

---

Or with `mapply` to multiply the corresponding columns of 'data.frame' and elements of 'vector'

```
mapply(`*`, d1, v1)
```

Comment: Sweep worked really well to multiple each column of matrix A by elements of coefficient matrix, and return matrix of similar dimension of matrix A

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few possibilities not mentioned yet:

**Base R**

```
t(replicate(nrow(d1), v1)) * d1
```

**purrr**

```
purrr::map2_dfc(d1, v1, `*`)
```

Note: as of `purrr` 1.0.0 `*_dfr` and `*_dfc` have been superseded so you can do:

```
purrr::map2(d1, v1, `*`) |> data.frame()
```

**collapse**

```
collapse::TRA(d1, v1, "*") # note quotes not backticks
```

---

The above is based on a numeric data frame. If you have other columns types, as mentioned in the comments, here are some options:

**By order**

If your numeric columns are in the same order as your vector, you can use the above, but subset for numeric columns first (just using my `replicate` answer as an example, but answers should work there too):

```
library(dplyr)

v1 <- c(-1, 0, 1, 100)
iris %>% 
  mutate(t(replicate(nrow(.), v1)) * pick(where(is.numeric)))
```

**Named vector**

Otherwise if you have name-value pairs where the names are the same as the columns that is easier:

```
v1 <- setNames(c(-1, 0, 1, 100), names(Filter(is.numeric, iris)))
iris %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(names(v1)), ~ . * v1[cur_column()]))
```